# Python 3.6: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] using SPARQL endpoint. Didn't happen before

Tags: sparql, python-3.6, sparqlwrapper

I have a script that gets results from a SPARQL, using the library SPARQLWrapper. It's been working perfectly well for the last 3 months, and now that I tried to run it again after a month break, it doesn't seem to work. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 132, in <module>
    download_lang(xml_dir, wav_dir, code)
  File "download.py", line 53, in download_lang
    recs = sparql_setup(pangloss)
  File "download.py", line 120, in sparql_setup
    results = sparql.query().convert()["results"]["bindings"]
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\SPARQLWrapper\Wrapper.py", line 798, in query
    return QueryResult(self._query())
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\SPARQLWrapper\Wrapper.py", line 766, in _query
    response = urlopener(request)
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Emre\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)>
```

How can I possibly fix this?

Comment: issue with the SPARQL endpoint? with your network? did you check the SPARQL endpoint in a browser or via curl? if you did *not* change anything on your machine it's most likely that the SPARQL endpoint did so.

Comment: @AKSW the endpoint seems to be running perfectly fine in a browser. Script however seems to not run on two machines, on which it used to run perfectly fine. Nothing has been changed on the machines.